# How to disable pgadmin webapplication?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I just installed PostgreSQL 10.4 and pgadmin4 was installed by default when I am opening pgadmin a web app opens in the browser.
I don't want to use pgadmin web app.
How can I open a pgadmin application instead rather than its browser version?

Here at download link `https://www.pgadmin.org/download/` it is written that pgAdmin 4 is a complete rewrite of pgAdmin, built using Python, and JavaScript/jQuery. A desktop runtime written in C++ with Qt allows it to run standalone for individual users, or the web application code may be deployed directly on the web server for use by one or more users through their web browser.

So it means that application is there but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the newer version of pgAdmin4 v3.0 they drop the support for desktop runtime application, means going forward it will be using default browser from user's system instead of C++/Qt5 runtime to render it's GUI.

Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3086

Comment: Yep, latest non-web desktop version was v2.1 https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/